# Delete a channel with a discord button

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am currently having issues with deleting a users ticket when a user with channel perms clicks it, but instead of just deleting the channel, it also creates a new one.. like what the heck?

I have a specific custom id for the close button aswell, but when i click the button it closes the ticket then creates a new one right away. So im not sure whats up with that, and ive tried to mess around with it to see if i can stop it from doing that, but to no avail.

I have a database for a support role to be added to tickets, so thats why I have 2 sections that look the same, but it is simply there to detect if the server has set a role to have access to tickets and if they have not set a role it will execute the other one.

```
const { MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton, ButtonInteraction } = require("discord.js");
const client = require("../index");
const supportSchema = require("../models/supportRole");

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isButton()) {
    if (interaction.customId === "tic") {
      let ticketChannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find((tc) => tc.name === `ticket-${interaction.user.id}`);
      let categoryChannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find((cc) => cc.name === "tickets");
      
      if (interaction.guild.channels.cache.find((ch) => ch.name === `ticket-${interaction.user.id}`)) return interaction.reply({ content: `<:CL_Support:912055272275599380> You currently have an open ticket.\n<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> <#${ticketChannel.id}>`, ephemeral: true });
      if (!interaction.guild.me.permissions.has("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) return interaction.reply({ content: "I do not have perms to create your ticket channel. - `[MANAGE_CHANNELS]`", ephemeral: true });
      
      let ticketCategory = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find((ch) => ch.name === "tickets");
      
      if (interaction.guild.channels.cache.some((type) => type.type === "GUILD_CATEGORY" && type.name === "tickets")) {
        console.log(`A new ticket has been created in ${interaction.guild.name}`);
      } else {
        const ticketCategory = interaction.guild.channels.create("tickets", {
            permissionOverwrites: [
              {
                id: interaction.guild.me.roles.highest,
                allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "ATTACH_FILES", "MANAGE_CHANNELS"],
              },
              {
                id: interaction.user.id,
                allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "ATTACH_FILES"],
              },
              {
                id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                deny: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "ATTACH_FILES"],
              },
            ],
            type: "GUILD_CATEGORY",
          }).catch();
      }
      
      supportSchema.findOne({ Guild: interaction.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
          if (!data) {
            const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${interaction.user.id}`, {
                parent: ticketCategory,
                topic: "Ticketing made easy, right at your fingertips!",
                permissionOverwrites: [
                  {
                    id: interaction.guild.me.roles.highest,
                    allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "ATTACH_FILES", "MANAGE_CHANNELS"],
                  },
                  {
                    id: interaction.user.id,
                    allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "ATTACH_FILES"],
                  },
                  {
                    id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                    deny: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "ATTACH_FILES"],
                  },
                ],
                type: "GUILD_TEXT",
              }).catch();
            
            const ticketEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle("__Support Ticket__")
              .setDescription("> Support will be with you shortly. While you wait, please let us know how we can help you today!\n\nClick on the ️ to close this ticket")
              .setColor("GREEN")
              .setFooter(`User ID: ${interaction.user.id}`, interaction.user.displayAvatarURL())
              .setTimestamp();
            
            const deleteTicket = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
              new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('delChannelWithoutData')
                .setLabel("️ Close")
                .setStyle("DANGER")
                .setDisabled(false)
            );
            
            interaction.reply({ content: `<:CL_Support:912055272275599380> Your ticket has been created!\n<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> <#${channel.id}>`, ephemeral: true });
            channel.send({ content: `@here <@${interaction.user.id}>`, embeds: [ticketEmbed], components: [deleteTicket] });
            
            const logchannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find((lc) => lc.name === "action-log");
            if (logchannel) {
              const ticketLogs = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Ticket Created")
                .addField("Name", `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> \`${channel.name}\``)
                .addField("Opened by", `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> \`${interaction.user.tag}\``)
                .addField("Created", `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> <t:${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}:R>`)
                .setFooter("Crimson - Ticket Logger", client.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .setColor("#5865F2")
                .setTimestamp();
              logchannel.send({ embeds: [ticketLogs] });
            }
          }
          if (data) {
            let role = data.Role;
            const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${interaction.user.id}`, {
                parent: ticketCategory,
                topic: "Ticketing made easy, right at your fingertips!",
                permissionOverwrites: [
                  {
                    id: interaction.guild.me.roles.highest,
                    allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "ATTACH_FILES", "MANAGE_CHANNELS"],
                  },
                  {
                    id: interaction.user.id,
                    allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "ATTACH_FILES"],
                  },
                  {
                    id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                    deny: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "ATTACH_FILES"],
                  },
                  {
                    id: role,
                    allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "ATTACH_FILES", "MANAGE_CHANNELS"],
                  },
                ],
                type: "GUILD_TEXT",
              }).catch();
            
            const ticketEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle("__Support Ticket__")
              .setDescription("> Support will be with you shortly. While you wait, please let us know how we can help you today!\n\nClick on the ️ to close this ticket")
              .setColor("GREEN")
              .setFooter(`User ID: ${interaction.user.id}`, interaction.user.displayAvatarURL())
              .setTimestamp();
            
            const deleteTicket = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
              new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('delChannelWithData')
                .setLabel("️ Close")
                .setStyle("DANGER")
                .setDisabled(false)
            );
            
            interaction.reply({ content: `<:CL_Support:912055272275599380> Your ticket has been created!\n<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> <#${channel.id}>`, ephemeral: true });
            channel.send({ content: `@here <@${interaction.user.id}>`, embeds: [ticketEmbed], components: [deleteTicket] });
            
            const logchannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find((lc) => lc.name === "action-log");
            if (logchannel) {
              const ticketLogs = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Ticket Created")
                .addField("Name", `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> \`${channel.name}\``)
                .addField("Opened by", `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> \`${interaction.user.tag}\``)
                .addField("Created", `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> <t:${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}:R>`)
                .setFooter("Crimson - Ticket Logger", client.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .setColor("#5865F2")
                .setTimestamp();
              logchannel.send({ embeds: [ticketLogs] });
            }
          }
        }
      );
    }
    
    if (interaction.customId === "delChannelWithData") {
      if (!interaction.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) {
        return interaction.reply({ content: 'You do not have perms to close this ticket. - `[MANAGE_CHANNELS]`', ephemeral: true });
      } else {
      interaction.reply("Closing ticket, please wait...").then(ch => {
        setTimeout(() => interaction.channel.delete(), 3000)
      }).catch();
      }
    }
  
    if (interaction.customId === "delChannelWithoutData") {
      if (!interaction.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) {
        return interaction.reply({ content: 'You do not have perms to close this ticket. - `[MANAGE_CHANNELS]`', ephemeral: true });
      } else {
      interaction.reply("Closing ticket, please wait...").then(ch => {
        setTimeout(() => interaction.channel.delete(), 3000)
      }).catch();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my problem after some debugging, I changed tons of things for no reason.. all I had to do was add a seperate `interaction.isButton` for the button.

```
if (interaction.isButton()) {
      if (interaction.customId === "delChannelWithoutData") {
         interaction.channel.delete();
      }
   }
```

I did the same with the other button for the customId of `delChannelWithData`